# Grant permission to read java home from untrusted java code

Tags: java

I'm loading untrusted code at runtime and for this reason I'm also writing a custom SecurityManager. This untrusted code however lazy-loads some JRE classes that I do not want to block. Would it be safe if I granted "read" permission to the whole JRE directory (System.getProperty("java.home");)? Otherwise, what are the reasons why doing this would be insecure?

Comment: "For example, granting permission to access the "java.home" system property gives potentially malevolent code sensitive information about the system environment (the location of the runtime environment's directory)." - http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html

Comment: The SecurityManager is not the place you want to do this sort of this. Code loaded by the boot class loader should have full permissions. Apply highly restricted permissions to the loaded classes. The mechanism is through `ProtectionDomain`s added through subclasses of `SecureClassLoader`.